# What is difference between "import {PROPERTY} from 'MODULE'" and "require(MODULE).PROPERTY"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

Now I'm studying 'react-native-router-flux' with 'react-redux'.
Beginning of my App.js Code is below.

```js
import { Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router);

import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
const logger = createLogger();

import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
const middleware = [logger, ReduxThunk];
```

I think this code is not neatly because I only use just one of Property from the Modules. Is there any better way to express it?

Maybe the below code is equal with above part of "logger".

```js
const logger = require('redux-logger').createLogger();
```

How these works are different between import {property} and require.property?

Comment: `import` and `export` are the JavaScript native standard module statements. The `require()` mechanism is quite different in detail, though of course it's intended to solve the same set of problems.

Comment: Also, I'm a beginner of ES6.

Comment: Well this is an important topic with a lot of history behind it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use import, Babel then transpire under the hood to require. Also require can require files dynamic.

Require is synchronous and import is asynchronous with better performance.
Require is a node.js way to import files.

I think that import export is more declarative.